# MQTT/TCP Timeout

Tags: tcp, mqtt

I wrote a simple program used to observe the MQTT connection state.

MQTT library choice <PubSubClient.h>

Only do MQTT Connect, but not do other things, like client.loop(keep connect)、disconnect.

When connecting successfully, and wait about 22s after, TCP sends [FIN, ACK] and [RST, ACK].

Is TCP timeout ?
And how to know TCP timeout value and view sessions from Wireshark .

Client: ESP8266 <-> MQTT Broker: Windows

Code:

```
    void MQTT_Setup(){
      client.setServer(MQTT_SERVER, MQTT_PORT);
      //client.setCallback(callback);
      MQTT_Connect();
    }
    
    void MQTT_Connect(){
      bool bMQTT;
      bMQTT = client.connect("ESP");
      Serial.println("MQTT Connected");
      if(bMQTT)MQTT_Disconnect();
      //MQTT_Publish();
    }
    void setup() {
    Serial.begin(BAUDRATE);
    delay(3000);
    WIFI_Setup();
    MQTT_Setup();
    }

    void loop() {
      //client.loop();
    }
```

Wireshark:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default MQTT Keep alive value for the PubSubClient can be found on line 36 of the [PubSubClient.h](https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient/blob/master/src/PubSubClient.h#L36)

The default is 15 seconds, brokers will wait for 1.5 the keep alive and if they have not received a packet from the client drop the connection.

```
15 * 1.5 ~= 22 seconds
```

This is why the connection is being closed. The `client.loop()` function will send the required ping packets to keep the connection alive if needed.

Comment: Now, I can understand why connect will close,
Otherwise,  about brokers wait for 1.5 the keep alive this one, where have document explain this? 
Thank you for your help!!

Comment: See section 3.1.2.10 in the 3.1.1 spec http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc385349237

Comment: Sorry, I try to understand from this document the Keep Alive,
It says "If the Keep-Alive value is non-zero and the Server does not receive a Control Packet from the Client within one and a half times the Keep Alive time period"

The client default Keep-Alive value is "15s", so if Server waits for over 7.5s( Half of 15 seconds ), So total wait time 15s + 7.5s ~= 22.5 seconds, the Server will disconnect.

Is there any error in understanding?

I don't know why is " Keep-Alive * 1.5 ", about  "1.5"  this one.
Why is it " * "  instead of  " + ".

Comment: "with in one (1) **and** a half (1/2)  times the keepalive" = (1 + 0.5)  * 15 =   22.5  = (integer maths round down) 22 seconds that the broker will wait for a packet before disconnecting the client. "times" is mulitply